# How to set selected value when using g:select in grails

Tags: html, grails, selected, selectedvalue

I'm newbie with Grails framwork.
I have issue:

I have Domain is: "Country". And I wants to show list country in select tag by using g:select in Grails

### For example: The data store in database can see below

### ID             Name

---

1              England
2              Canada
3              Germany

Now, I wants set "Canada" is selected.
Who can help me. Please!

Answer (score 9):

Use the value attribute to set the selected item:

```
<g:select name="user.company.id"
from="${Company.list()}"
value="${user?.company.id}"
optionKey="id" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`g:countrySelect`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/countrySelect.html) tag? This will save One whole Domain.

Comment: This really should be a comment instead of an answer, but I'm voting it up because it's useful and relevant.

Comment: interesting. I have never see g:XXXSelect before. could you point me to where this is documented?  Also need to be able to specify which is the "selected" item.

Answer (score 1):

Use the select tag structure provided by mpccolorado, then to have Canada selected by default change the `value` to:

```
value="2"
```

(the Id for Canada).